# How can I look at the MQTT log in Bluemix IoTF

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot, node-red

I'm using Node-RED on Bluemix to talk to an Arduino Uno with a temperature sensor. I'm using a recipe that publishes the temperature to a MQTT Topic and have added code from the example that comes with the paho pubsubclient library by @knolleary to add code to subscribe to a MQTT topic.  I'm getting errors when trying to subscribe. How can I look at the MQTT logs to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Did you try the "cf logs" command for your application?

Comment: What MQTT broker are you using? You can not see the logs from the IoTF service as it's a shared broker

Answer (score 0):

To see your Bluemix application logs, you need to have cloud foundry installed.  You can then use the "cf" commands to view logs.  As for the logs from the IoTF service itself most of that information is only viewable by the IoTF Bluemix support team as mentioned in the comment above.